# "Bundle" backend (Node) and frontend (Angular) applications into one for production

Tags: node.js, angular, gulp

I have a simple REST backend served by Node and an Angular 9 application that communicates with it to manage the business logic. Right now, they are deployed in two separate folders on the production server:

```
/opt/git/cargo-backend          Node application 
/var/www/cargo-frontend         Angular application
```

For technical reasons (the customer has a new server with Plesk control panel), both backend and frontend compiled sources should be "bundled" together into a new Git project so that, to upload a new version of the application, the customer only has to do a `git pull` from his Plesk panel. The folder structure for the deployed app should be like this:

```
    /
    ... bin/
    ... config/
    ... db/
    ... FRONTEND/        ---> The compiled Angular app should go in here
    ... middleware/
    ... node_modules/
    [etc]
    ... app.js
    ... package.json
```

As you can see, basically it's the backend sources with a folder (`FRONTEND`) that contains the Angular compiled code. My idea is to create a new Git project with an script that would copy the Node folder (without node_modules) and that would compile the Angular application and copy the resulting files to the `FRONTEND` sub-folder. I'm thinking of using `Gulp` or even a bash script, but I'd like to get some ideas, if someone has been in the same case.

**EDIT**

Finally, I've chosen to use Git *submodules*. Now the `FRONTEND` folder is a submodule pointing to the compiled Angular app repository, so I can deploy the backend-frontend with a single `git pull --recurse-submodules`.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use ng build to build your application and put all content of dist folder inside cargo-folder content. and to serve cargo-content folder from node server use the link below as reference.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Hi! In this case, I can't do it, because we need the `FRONTEND` folder to be served by nginx on a subdomain.  Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Then they are two different application. what did you mean by bundling as one?

Comment: you can have your backend nodejs code in backend folder and frontendcode in frontend folder. and entrypoint of nodejs application inside backend folder and build frontend folder separately and deploy on nginx.

Comment: By "bundling" I meant to deploy both applications at once. I know it's not the best word to describe it (that's why I put it in quotes), sorry for the confusion!